# How to apply integrals and derivatives in physics?

Tags: integration, derivatives, physics

We have learned how to count integrals and derivatives in maths and we were told we would use this in physics but how do I know when to use integral and when I should differentiate? I know that integral is an area under the curve, but how do I know what the area represents? for eg how do i know that when i make a graph of dependence of velocity on time, that the area under the curve is the $s$ and that the derivative would be $a$?

Answer (score 5):

You'll know from context once you've learned a bit more of the subject. One common trick is dimensional analysis. For example, do you think we get velocity by differentiating or integrating position with respect to time? Well, since $v$ has the units of $x/t$, it has the units of $dx/dt$. Similarly, $x$ has the units of $vt$, i.e. those of $\int v dt$. Oh, look! Differentiating $x$ gives $v$; integrating $v$ gives $t$. The reverse would be dimensionally inconsistent. That $a=dv/dt$ as opposed to $v=da/dt$ follows similarly.

Comment: "Oh, look!" :) (+1)

Comment: I think this is example is doubtful. It's bad, if you want to be rigorous, because the velocity is defined as $\dot{r}$. However, it really shows the power of the dimensional analysis. (+1)

Comment: @Botond Anyone who felt the need to ask which way the derivative goes is less likely to get that point than they are to remember velocity is measured in metres per second, or that the constant-velocity special case gives $x=vt$.

Comment: @J.G. Yes, I know. That's why I said that it's a great example at the same time. But I thought it's worth to mention. :)